# I can't install 'ReportViewerMVC 12.0.0'. I keep getting this error. Please Anyone?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget-package, reportviewer

I created ASP.Net MVC application under.NETFramework 4.5, later I changed it to 4.5.2 to get reportviewer function. But I get this error when I install NuGet package for ReportviewerMVC.

Here is the error. Please help me.

Could not install package 'ReportViewerMVC 12.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.         0

Comment: The error is completely self-explanatory. Please read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the newest version of  report viewer you better update your project to .NET Framework 4.6 or any newer version. But you can use your version too. At first you have to install package using nuget package manager

```
Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms
```

After this configure your project using this link :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started?view=sql-server-ver15